# ASP.NET C# DropDownList dúvida

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho um módulo que gera relatórios em `excel`, sendo um desses relatórios,o módulo chamado de Ocorrências. Onde através de `DropDownList` ele me informa todos os registros da tabela `OcorrTipoEntr`, que tem as colunas `OctCodigo` e `OctDesc` porém nesse `ddl` ele apenas me trás a descrição da ocorrência:

> Destinatário Ausente

Na classe que informa essa consulta `TipoOcorrencia.cs` ele apenas faz uma consulta simples `SELECT * FROM OcorrTipoEntr` pois como disse, preciso de toda carga de dados que existe nessa tabela.

Porém preciso que nesse `ddl` informe o código da ocorrência, seguido da descrição.Exemplo:

> 46 - Destinatário Ausente

Minha dúvida é, onde eu posso aplicar essa alteração?

No `jQuery`, no `code-behind`, na classe? Seria apenas uma concatenação?

Comment: É AspNETMVC ??? Se tem o código que faz o Envio dessa informação para tela ??? Seu banco é SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa é uma saída para quem usa WebForms...

HTML do Formulário

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOcorrencias" runat="server" OnDataBound="ddlOcorrencias_DataBound"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
</form>
```

Classe de Ocorrencias

```
public class Ocorrencias
{
    public Ocorrencias()
    {

    }

    public String Ocorrencia { get; set; }

    public string CodigoOcorrencia { get; set; }
}
```

Page_Load do DropDownList para populá-lo

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Ocorrencias> Ocorr = new List<Ocorrencias>();

        Ocorrencias Oc1 = new Ocorrencias();
        Oc1.CodigoOcorrencia = "45";
        Oc1.Ocorrencia = "Alguma Ocorrencia Ocorreu !";

        Ocorrencias Oc2 = new Ocorrencias();
        Oc2.CodigoOcorrencia = "46";
        Oc2.Ocorrencia = "Destinatário Ausente";

        Ocorr.Add(Oc1);
        Ocorr.Add(Oc2);

        ddlOcorrencias.DataValueField = "CodigoOcorrencia";
        ddlOcorrencias.DataTextField = "Ocorrencia";
        ddlOcorrencias.DataSource = Ocorr;
        ddlOcorrencias.DataBind();
    }
```

Concatenação no DataBound do DropDownList

```
    protected void ddlOcorrencias_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListItem li in ddlOcorrencias.Items)
        {
            li.Text = li.Value + " - " + li.Text;
        }
    }
```